# How do I hide UI elements on a tap of the View, using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uigesturerecognizer

Just as `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true` hides the navigation bar, how do I hide regular UI elements like buttons, labels etc. with a tap of the view? I made a PDF viewer from scratch and now I need a method that will hide the UI elements on the view with a tap, just like the Photos app does on an iPhone.

Here is the code I attempted to use, but no success:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        var dismissTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("dismissViewElements:"))

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)

    }

    func dismissViewElements(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            self.backButton.alpha = 0
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. On tap of the view, you want to hide a bunch of "tools" (edit buttons, etc...). The app that comes to mind is the photo viewer app that comes with iPhones, when you tap once, the edit/crop/back buttons etc... all hide.

The easiest way to do this (in my opinion) is to add all these ui controls to a parent view, on a separate "layer". and have that layer be the top layer. When a user taps this view, (as long as its not a button or something inside the parent view) the view disappears (along with all its children buttons/controls/etc.)

I would personally use touchesEnded because its really easy to implement. heres what the `touchesEnded` method should look like (more or less)

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.hidden = true
        //where parentView is the parent view, whatever you named it
    }
```

and you should be all set I think

also, I forgot to mention, you should subclass a `UIView` and have the `touchesEnded` inside this particular implementation of the `UIView` and in the storyboard, you can click the `UIView` that you're using as a parent, and give it a class type of whatever you named the subclass

I pushed up a quick project for you on [github](https://github.com/ahmadabdul3/HideButtonsSwift) to illustrate the idea

---

***Update - make elements appear again***

you can do something very similar. Have a parent `UIVIew`, with a child `UIVIew` inside of it, and all the buttons/tools inside of the child `UIView`. This way, on `touchesEnded` of the parent `UIView` you can hide the child `UIView` and on `touchesEnded` again make the child `UIView` reappear. all you have to do inside `touchesEnded` is the following:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            childUiView.hidden = !childUiView.hidden
        }
```

this way, every time you touch it, it will assign `hidden` to the opposite of what it was.

Comment: this method helps them disappear on tap, but how do I make them re-appear on tap as well

Comment: you can do something very similar. Have a parent `UIVIew`, with a child `UIVIew` inside of it, and all the buttons/tools inside of the child `UIView`. This way, on `touchesEnded` of the parent `UIView` you can hide the child `UIView` and on `touchesEnded` again make the child `UIView` reappear. all you have to do inside `touchesEnded` is the following: `childUiView.hidden = !childUiView.hidden;` this way, every time you touch it, it will assign `hidden` to the opposite of what it was. I'll update the answer with this as well

Answer (score 0):

You must add a `Tap gesture recognizer` to your item and then make an outlet/action. In this action you set the alpha or the hidden property.

Comment: but how should the code look like, for instance, If I want to dismiss a button on my view with a tap of the view.

Comment: Have you ever used an application that dismisses the navigation bar and toolbar with a tap of the view? particularly PDF/Book reading applications? well I want to apply that same tap to dismiss method but on regular UI Elements such as buttons, labels, etc. Not a navigation bar or tool bar

Answer (score 0):

Your question is awfully vague/broad. What part of this do you need help with? What have you tried?

In very general terms:

Create a tap gesture recognizer. Attach it to the view that you want to tap. Have it call a method in your view controller. Let's call that method toggleControls:

The method needs to take the gesture recognizer as a parameter.

Add a Bool property controlsAreHidden to your VC.

in the toggleControls method, switch the state of controlsAreHidden.

Write code that shows the controls when controlsAreHidden == true, and hides them when controlsAreHidden == false.

Comment: Have you ever used an application that dismisses the navigation bar and toolbar with a tap of the view? particularly PDF/Book reading applications? well I want to apply that same tap to dismiss method but on regular UI Elements such as buttons, labels, etc. Not a navigation bar or tool bar

Comment: What part of this do you need help with? What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried adding a tapGesture, adding it as a subView to my view

Comment: and its action fading the alpha of a specific UIButton when the view is tapped

Comment: So edit your question to include all the relevant code.